# Tell Django not to save a model field

Tags: python, django

I want to tell Django not to save my `image` model field.

Here's my view call:

```
def post(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        form_post = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form_post.is_valid():
            instance = form_post.save(commit=False)

            #if something:
                #don't save instance.image

        else:
            form_post = PostForm()

        context = {
            'form_post': form_post,
        }

        return render(request, 'post/post.html', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/signup/")
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the field later, just set it to `None` before you save (assuming you've set up your model such that `image` can be null)

```
    if form_post.is_valid():
        instance = form_post.save(commit=False)

        if something:
            instance.image = None

        instance.save()
```